# IntelliJ can't use ALT key after computer shutdown unexpected

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, shutdown

I met a strange error in IntelliJ IDEA 14.

My laptop was working with IDEA and I plugged the phone to debug my project. But the laptop was shutdown unexpected after that.

I restart my laptop and open up the IDEA again, some of my ALT shortcut keys didn't work anymore. Having reinstall the IDEA but the problem not solved.

The IDEA throws a message like this:

> Cannot read scheme Default copy.xml  from '$ROOT_CONFIG$/keymaps': java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected content storage modification 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected content storage modification

Any idea for this? I'm scaring the IntelliJ IDEA will crash later if my laptop still shutdown unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your app include all the setting, plugin, history and then download the lasted IntelliJ IDEA from Jetbrains. Then install it to another folder will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need to uninstall,just remove your android configuration files.

In Linux system, it is in **.AndroidStudio[VERSION]/config/tasks/**,remove the corresponding tasks and restart Android Studio,it **will regenerate** the configuration files in this directory.